# jenkins with iOS

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcode-plugin

I am new to jenkins and I refer 4-5 links for integration jenkins with my iOS project. Right now I got successfully retrive repo from gitlab and after that pod installation is completed.

Now, as a configure xcode build configuration, it will give me error like -scheme is not available. I tried too many option and I select xcode scheme file as "Pods-projectname".

It will take successfully and at last give me error like You have to provide a value for either the marketing or technical version. Found neither.”

Now, I am confuse to configure jenkins with my project. 
So, please some one help me to configure my project with jenkins that how can I build .ipa with jenkins. Right now I have mac mini and run jenkins as a localhost:8080.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You can refer to https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2017/12/one-stop-solution-for-setting-up-ci-and.html I have detailed explanation on how to configure Jenkins to work with Xcode . I have used manual code signing if you need automatic code signing to archive and export archive xcodebuild command add -allowProvisioningUpdate